How do I use "batcat" to colorize the output of the "--help" and "-h" options of commands?
I would like to use batcat to colorize the output of the --help and -h options of commands, similar to the use of batcat colorization of the man pages.
I would like this to work on different shells, including Bash and Zsh.
There is a solution for the manpages where within the .*rc file (.bashrc or .zshrc) is added:
export MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | batcat -l man -p'"
export MANROFFOPT="-c"

Is there an environment variable that can be used in a similar way for the --help/-h option?
Writing a function for it or piping it after every --help/-h query, like | bat -l help, doesn't look to be the most "beautiful" way to do this.

Commands all implement --help in their own ways, there's no standard (except maybe for GNU commands, but even then only for formatting and conventions). Many don't even have --help, but only -h, for instance, and a few pipe the output to a pager automatically (e.g., aws CLI), most dump the text to stderr but some output to stdout, etc., etc.

Not what you're asking for.
But at least for commands supported by batcat -l help you could make use of some "syntactic sugar" instead of typing the whole thing in every time:
ch() { "${1}" --help | batcat -l help; }

In ~/.bashrc / ~/.zshrc.
Use only with Bash builtins or GNU programs (as those seem to be supported by batcat -l help: printf, find... - contrarily to what I stated in the comments, it won't work for Zsh builtins).
Usage:
ch <command>

ch find


